# What does this C symbol mean?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, notation

Problem from China Olympiad

[image]

What does the capital C symbol mean?

Comment: Probably binomial coefficient (combinations, sometimes written as ${}_n C_r$)

Comment: [The binomial coefficient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: $\mathrm{C}_n^k$ refers to the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$.

Comment: The larger number appears on the top and smaller on the bottom for that symbol.

Comment: I will point out that there are a good dozen or so notations for the binomial coefficient.  Some people notate it as $C^n_k$ while other people notate it as $C^k_n$, both to mean the algebraic expression $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.  It is unfortunate that there are so many conflicting notations, which is why I strongly recommend swapping to the superior and the seemingly more common notation $\binom{n}{k}$ to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the binomial coefficient. There are 3 ways to write it in China:

- In mainland, we prefer
  $$C_n^r=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}.$$
- In Hong Kong, we prefer
  $$nCr=C_r^n=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}.$$

All are acceptable.

Comment: As a student studying maths in Hong Kong, I do not see the preference.

Comment: @Szeto There is a high school elective course (mathematics extended part module 2) that teaches the symbol $C_r^n$. HKDSE would mark the notation $C_n^r$ zero. Nonetheless, the notations don't really matter in the University in HK.